# add multiples files to an array in perl

Tags: arrays, list, perl

I have some txt files with a huge list of lines like:

```
file_1.txt        file_2.txt      file_3.txt
XP_001703830.1    XP_001703820.1  XP_001703810.1
XP_001703836.1    XP_001703815.1  XP_001703805.1
XP_001703844.1    XP_001703834.1  XP_001703844.1
```

let's say that I have 10 or more files in a folder, and I want to read all of them and store the content in a array, I have used this code, but it just store one line of a file, and not all the lines !!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

my @files = glob("*.txt");
my @ID;

for my $file(@files) {
    open IN, '<', $file or die "$!";
        while (<IN>) {
            my $fields = $_;
            push @ID, $fields;
        }
}

foreach (@ID){
    print "$_\n";
}
close IN;
exit;
```

what I want is store all the lines in a  array like:

```
XP_001703830.1      
XP_001703836.1      
XP_001703844.1      
XP_001703820.1
XP_001703815.1
XP_001703834.1
XP_001703810.1
XP_001703805.1
XP_001703844.1
```

Thanks So Much !!!

Comment: First `close IN;` should be under `for` loop where you are opening a txt file.

Comment: I am perfectly able to store all the lines in a array using your exact code!! What are you getting in `@ID`?

Comment: Why are you reinventing `cat`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are anyway reading entire stuff into memory ( not usually the best use of RAM ) then you could do this ...  perl TIMTOWTDI

```
my @ID;
{
    local(@ARGV) =  glob("*.txt");
    @ID=<>;
}
print "@ID\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

By initializing default input separator as undef this can be solved,

```
use strict;
my @files = glob("*.txt");
my @ID;

for my $file(@files) {
    open IN, '<', $file or die "$!";
    while (<IN>) {
        my $fields = do{local $/; <IN>};
        push @ID, $fields;
    }
}

foreach (@ID){
    print "$_\n";
}
close IN;
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a problem with line terminators. Try

```
open IN, '<:crlf', $file
```